# How to convert Bipartite Perfect Matching to SAT?

Tags: reductions, np, satisfiability, bipartite-matching, 3-sat

SAT is $NP$-complete while Bipartite Perfect Matching is in NC under derandomization assumptions. How to convert Bipartite Perfect Matching from balanced bipartites to SAT without Cook-Levin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 3-SAT is NP-complete you can take any algorithm that decides bipartite perfect matching and use the construction from [Cook-Levin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem). A direct construction is as follows.

Let $G=(U+V, E)$ be the bipartire graph with $|U| \le |V|$ and no isolated vertices.
Create a boolean variable $x_e$ for each edge $e \in E$. Intuitively, $x_e$ is set to true iff $e$ is selected in the matching.

Then, for all (unordered) pairs of distinct edges $\{e, f\}$ such that $e$ and $f$ share an endpoint, add the clause $(\overline{x}_e \vee \overline{x}_f)$. These clauses ensure that the selected edges form a matching.

Finally, for each vertex $u \in U$, create a new clause $\bigvee\limits_{ e=(u,v) \in E} x_e$. Intuitively, this clause is satisfied iff $u$ is matched.

The SAT formula $\varphi$ obtained as the conjunction of all the above clauses is satisfiable iff $G$ admits a perfect matching. To obtain a 3-SAT formula you can apply the standard transformation from SAT to 3-SAT.
Essentially, you can suitably duplicate and pad clauses with less than $3$ literals, while a generic clause $(\ell_1 \vee \ell_2 \vee \dots, \ell_k)$ with $k > 3$ literals can be replaced by the two clauses $(\ell_1 \vee \ell_2 \vee y) \wedge (\overline{y} \vee  \ell_3 \vee  \ell_4 \vee  \dots \vee  \ell_k)$, where $y$ is a new variable. Repeat the above transformation until all clauses have exactly 3 literals.